# Do you know a way to record vibration with a Raspberry?

Tags: sensor

I study mechanical vibration, for my Ph.D. And in few months, I have the possibility the present an installation, which show my work. I would like to create something interactive which record the vibration of a piece of metal for example. 
This Installation will be a very quick game. The user will have to predict the time it take for a structure to stop vibrate.
for the IOM : I think the best way is to have a numeric keypad for the estimation of the user. If it's possible, I would love to show the result on screen. But two led could be a solution.

Do you know any installation which is close to what I want to do?

Do you know how which device I should use to record the vibration?

I thought about using a sound card, by the sound will  very very low.

Another option could be an accelerometer board, like in a smartphone. Like This one on [ozzmaker.com](http://ozzmaker.com/guide-to-interfacing-a-gyro-and-accelerometer-with-a-raspberry-pi/).
But the sample rate seems a little bit low, only 100Hz. And I pretty sure it will saturate really quickly. It's look complex and I don't want to spend too much time on it.

The best option I found is that : 
[adafruit.com/product](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1766)
I would like something more analogic, but this could do the job.

Any other proposition?

Comment: "Something more analogic" -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor   It's not clear from that how simple they potentially are, so e.g. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10293 ; adafruit sells one too but I believe A) They are generally 5v, B) You'll need a ADC with the pi.  Mine are still sitting in the toy chest so I can't provide a full answer about how sensitive they are.   If you do have an ADC and are ordering something else it's probably worth the $2 gamble to investigate

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Raspberry Pi to record the vibration. HOWEVER, I think what you're actually asking is what transducer you might use to detect the vibration.

When selecting transducer, please bear in mind that the sampling rate of vibration is very different to the transducer's voltage sampling rate. The output of the transducer may only 100 times per second, but that does not mean that it will only detect 100Hz vibrations.

The Adafruit device will certainly tell you when vibrations of a certain amplitude have stopped. This amplitude is fixed by the nature of the hardware. Further, you must be very careful how you mount it. If you mount it in the same axis as the vibration, be prepared that it will switch on and off at the frequency of the vibration (or some harmonic thereof). As such it will not be an "on = vibrating, off = not vibrating".

You game, as you describe it, is over-simplified. How do you definitively say that the structure has stopped vibrating? My understanding of physics is that everything vibrates all the time, unless you can manage to attain 0 Kelvin.

I feel that there's a lot of detail missing from your question, but I'm sure that what you really want is an accelerometer such as the ozzmaker product and not a "vibration sensor."

Any I2C based accelerometer will suit your purpose. Make sure to select the correct range. The options are often +/- 2g and +/-10g. Your software will have to be moderately clever to convert the acceleration into vibration.

Give more details. Ask more questions.